# Problem with Google BigQuery Rest API via Power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a problem scheduling refresh in the Power Bi service for the google Big Query database. 
It used to work fine and since last Friday Power Bi cannot connect to gbq anymore. 
I tried Microsoft Support but they send me to you.

This is the error I receive:

> ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with REST API: Couldn't connect to server ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverOAuthSupport] (8701) Error interacting with REST API: Couldn't connect to server Table: CS_Scorecard.
>   Cluster URI:    WABI-WEST-EUROPE-B-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
>   Activity ID:    07d42767-95e3-4bbc-81e8-6953be164caa
>   Request ID: f1b4b205-4228-4f16-8d6d-e98b28eec5c7
>   Time:   2019-12-10 12:43:12Z

I tried creating a new model with 1 gbq link and that worked fine. But my existing model is failing right now.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

According with [Power BI support](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Error-Interacting-with-REST-API-while-connecting-to-Google/td-p/438707) page this issue is known.

Seems that the issue may be caused by a lack of permissions for the user attempting to establish a connection.

You will need to check that the account being used has the appropriate permissions, in particular "bigquery.tables.list" permission needs to be assigned. 
Check the [BigQuery roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#role_types).

I suggest confirming that there are no [custom IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#custom_roles) or [roles type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#role_types) set up on the dataset(s) you are trying to connect to.

Verify that you are using the last version of [Simba drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/).

Finally you can look the following [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/145895341), where this issue was reported.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.
The Power Bi user has the Data Viewer role and we haven't any custom role on this dataset.

About the driver, we are trying to refresh a dataflow on the PBI Server, not in Desktop, so I guess the driver is updated.

Thank you.